# SSRS report export error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report which pulls data from a stored procedure. The report works perfectly fine on the web when im running it with different parameters. However, I get a duplicate row when im trying to export the ssrs report to excel.

Comment: what data does your stored procedure return in (SSMS) with the same parameters? Does it show duplicate rows in SQL?

Comment: The SQL doesn't return any duplicates. It's just when i export the report to excel, it gives me duplicate

Comment: Are all the rows duplicated?

Comment: No only one row is duplicating

Comment: Could you please show the output in excel and the report design layout (images)

Comment: I figured it out. The actual SQL didnt have a select distinct, which caused the duplication of the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual reason why the row was duplicating was because of the stored procedure. Instead of distincting the selected values it was picking up duplicates.

```
Select DISTINCT
```

There fore using a simple sql fixed it.

Comment: so the SQL WAS returning duplicates like I had asked you to check!